# Querying an array of objects in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```
myTable
{
 "creator": "xyz@gmail.com",
 "data": {
  "sections" : [],
  "sharing": [
    {
     "key": "value",
      "user": "abc@gmail.com"
    },
    {
     "key": "value",
     "user": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    {
     "key": "value",
     "user": "qwe@gmail.com"
    }
   }
}
```

I have above table stored in postgres, and data column stored in jsonb format, I want to query with user email eg. `user : qwe@gmail.com`

I have tried below query but the response is slow

`SELECT creator, data - 'sections' AS data FROM myTable WHERE (data->'sharing')::text LIKE '%qwe@gmail.com%' ORDER BY xmin::text::bigint DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the contains [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) `@>`

```
select ..
from mytable
where data -> 'sharing' @> '[{"user": "qwe@gmail.com"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working its not returning anything `SELECT creator, data FROM myTable where data->'sharing' @> '{"user" : "qwe@gmail.com"}'`

Comment: Ah, sorry. The parameter also needs to be an array. See my edit